# As much as I can or would I be able to?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, conditional-constructions, will-would

Which one is correct?

**1)If I were you, I would save money as much as I can**

or

**2)If I were you, I would save money as much as I would be able to**

Comment: Why do you think one is incorrect? What precise meaning are you trying to convey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the choice between your two sentences, the second is better

> If I were you, I would save money as much as I would be able to

However, maybe your first sentence should read

> If I were you, I would save money as much as I *could*

which would make it a better choice than the second.